# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post') Posting to Azure web API from SPFX

Tags: spfx-webparts, api, azure-functions, post

I hope someone can help me with this.
I’m getting error message **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')**.
The Azure function is working fine and is used in other projects.

[image: strong text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your `context` object or your `HttpClient` is null. If you're calling this from a component you'll need to pass those objects from the web part into the component.

But best practice is to just pass the `HttpClient` and not the context object.